# Zend Framework Route Chaining not work as expected

Tags: zend-framework, routes, chaining

I'm using ZF 1.11 for my project. 
This is my routing configuration:

```
    public function _initRoutes() {

                $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
                $frontController->throwExceptions(false);
                $router = $frontController->getRouter(); // returns a rewrite router by default

                $langRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                                ':lang/', array(
                            'lang' => 'vn'
                                )
                );

                $manufactureRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
                            'manufacture/(\d+)-(.+).html',
                            array(
                                'module' => 'default',
                                'controller' => 'index',
                                'action' => 'filter'
                            ),
                            array(
                                '1' => 'manufacture_id',
                                '2' => 'manufacture_name',
                            ),
                            'manufacture/%d-%s.html'
                );
                $manufactureRoute = $langRoute->chain($manufactureRoute);
                $router->addRoute('manufactureRoute', $manufactureRoute);


        $frontController->setRouter($router);
}
```

When user access URLs like :

```
http://mydomain.vn/**vn**/manufacture/1-apple.html
```

everything works well as expected.

But the URLs like these below work well too.

```
http://mydomain.vn/**abc**/manufacture/1-apple.html
http://mydomain.vn/**def**/manufacture/1-apple.html
```

How can I make sure that user is accessing my correct URLs (with "vn"), all others are redirected to my custom 404 page.

I tried to redirect all the incorrect URLs to 404 page by setting rule in htaccess file but not success.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|txt|png|jpg|gif|flv|swf|resource|publics|uploads|robots)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

***RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vn/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /vn/$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]***

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.vn [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.vn/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.vn/index.php/(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.vn/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems like the requirements for your route are:

1. a fixed list of supported languages; and
2. the lang value is captured into a request parameter.

So, how about turning the lang route from a `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` route into `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` route with pattern something like:

```
(\(vn\))
```

The outer parens are for parameter identification, the standard regex delineation; the inner parens are escaped as part of an (at this moment, trivial) "or" condition.

Then when you add more languages - say 'en' or 'de' or whatever - you could modify the pattern to a less trivial "or" condition:

```
(\(vn|en|de\))
```

Not directly tested, just thinking out loud...